# WTForms , form with more than one SelectField? Does SelectFieldArray exists?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to find better solution for this. My solution now is very awkward (but works), because if i wanted like 20 selectfields... u can imagine how horrible and long will template look like etc... 
so basically what i'm asking is, if some SelectFieldArray object  exists in WTForm? i didnt find in documentation. 

So here's my awkward solution for now:
In my view method i do this:

```
form = ResultForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    print form.f1.data
    print form.f2.data
```

my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %} 
<form method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>
        <label for="title">
            {{form.f1.label}}
        </label><br/>
        {{form.f1}}
         <label for="title">
            {{form.f2.label}}
        </label><br/>
        {{form.f2}}

        {% if form.f1.errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in form.f1.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% if form.f2.errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in form.f1.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

my WTForm class:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, PasswordField,SelectField,validators
from wtforms.validators import Required
class ResultForm(Form):
f1 = SelectField(u'f1',
            coerce=int,
            validators=[validators.optional()],
            choices=[(1, 'A'),(2, 'B'),(3, 'C'),(4, 'D'),(5, 'E'),(6, 'FX'),(7, 'na')])
f2 = SelectField(u'f2',
            coerce=int,
            validators=[validators.optional()],
            choices=[(1, 'A'),(2, 'B'),(3, 'C'),(4, 'D'),(5, 'E'),(6, 'FX'),(7, 'na')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have one field repeated you can use `wtforms.fields.FieldList` (see the documentation about [Field Closures](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#field-enclosures)):

```
class ResultForm2(BaseForm):
    selects = FieldList(SelectField(u'Select', coerce=int,
                                    validators=[validators.optional()],
                                    choices=[(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'),
                                             (4, 'D'), (5, 'E'), (6, 'FX'),
                                             (7, 'na')]), min_entries=2)
```

That produces two select inputs with names "select-0" and "selects-1" (because of min_entries set to two). Both have identical data though.

You can also create forms dynamically (see documentation about [Dynamic Form Composition](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/specific_problems.html#dynamic-form-composition)), for example:

```
def my_dynamic_form(select_field_count=20):
    class F(MyBaseForm):
        pass
    for i in range(select_field_count):
        setattr(F, 'f%d' % i, SelectField('F%d' % i, coerce=int,
                                        validators=[validators.optional()],
                                        choices=[(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'),
                                                 (4, 'D'), (5, 'E'), (6, 'FX'),
                                                 (7, 'na')]))
    return F
```

This way the form can be constructed completely dynamic, for example SelectFields could have different choices.

Comment: i answered your question, just i forgot i was logged in w/ 'marhula' account .... anyway my answer was too long for comment

Comment: dat looks probably like something i have been searching for. Thx. I will try it out, and let you know if it helped

Comment: btw could u add what to do in my View method with that FieldList? How can i in view method access selected option of each Selectfield?

Comment: You can access the field just like with a normal form. For example, if field `f1` exists you can do `form.f1` or `form.data['f1']`.

Comment: then how are  u gonna iterate in jinja template over  created f1,f2,... fX?
cant write {{f}}number .... totally cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

@oliverdm
 i cant even make comment on your response without 50reputation... n/c

what i'm trying to do is this:

```
<form action="">
<select name="" id=""></select>
<select name="" id=""></select>
<select name="" id=""></select>
<select name="" id=""></select>
<select name="" id=""></select>
<select name="" id=""></select>
 </form>
```

without doing this...

```
class ResultForm(Form):
  f1 = SelectField(u'f1',...
  f2 = SelectField(u'f2',...
  f3 = SelectField(u'f3',...
  f4 = SelectField(u'f4',...
  f5 = SelectField(u'f5',...
```

and then with view method do something like form[i].data ... or something....
Is this what your code example does?